# Update a div tag using Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, auto-update

I want to update a div tag(Holder) which contains a pie chart, I send values to the pie chart everytime the page loads (ResponseMetric.aspx). I am using jQuery for that purpose to update only the div tag(holder) but nothing happens, I change the value in the DB so that on page load a new value is passed. It doesnt do any page load. the values in the pie chart remains the same, where I am going wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRandom() {
        $("#holder").hide("slow");
        $("#holder").load("ResponseMetric.aspx", '', callback);
    }

    function callback() {
        $("#holder").show("slow");
        setTimeout("getRandom();", 4000);
    }

    $(document).ready(getRandom);
</script>
```

On page load I pass the values to the pie chart which is inside the Holder (Div) tag. the data for the pie chart changes every second so basically the pie chart has to be updated every 4 seconds, but it does not

Comment: What data does load receive? And what did you expect it to receive instead?

Comment: Check your network traffic, via [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/), for example. Another tip: Replace `setTimeout("getRandom();", 4000)` by `setTimeout(getRandom,4000)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and did only slight modifications in a jsfiddle

```
$(function() {
function getRandom() {
    alert("getRandom");
    $("#holder").hide("slow");
    $("#holder").load("/echo/html/", 'text', callback);
}

function callback() {
    $("#holder").show("slow");
    alert("callback");
    setTimeout(getRandom, 4000);
}
$(document).ready(getRandom);
 });
```

And this worked for me, notice the only difference really being not string-encapsulating the function call in setTimeout